# Windows executable got executed on my linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, exe

I wrote a simple code and compiled using g++ in linux in .exe format, suprisingly it got executed in my linux terminal. Can u say the reason for this ? Can linux terminal execute machine code in any format ? Can I run the same in windows ?
Code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World !"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile code:

```
g++ main.cpp -o program.exe
```

OS: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon.
I execute by typing `./program.exe`

Comment: Ah, no that is not building a windows excuteable. Just because you name it `exe` does not make it a Windows binary. It's still a normal Linux executable. Linux doesn't care what you name the file.

Comment: So this wont run on windows right ?

Comment: In POSIX systems like Linux there's no special format for file-names. You can name your programs anything you like. The`.exe` suffix is just part of the file name, it doesn't tell the compiler or linker to generate a program in a specific format.

Comment: That's right. It won't run natively on Windows.

Comment: Sadly, painting "Space-X" on the side of your Honda won't make it possible to drive it to Mars.

Comment: @kaylum "*It won't run natively on Windows*" - actually, under the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), it *might* actually run on Windows as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wrote a simple code and compiled using g++ in linux in .exe format, suprisingly it got executed in my linux terminal

There's nothing "surprising".  I assume you compiled it under Linux?  So why shouldn't you be able to *run* it under Unix?

> Will an .exe I build on Windows run on Linux (if I copied the binary)?

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: you can install [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) to run Windows applications on Linux.

> Will an .exe I build on Ubuntu run on Windows?

No.

> Does an executable I build on Ubuntu need to have the suffix .exe?

No.  File suffixes are irrelevant.

> Does an executable I build on Windows need to have the suffix .exe?

Yes.

---

To answer your additional questions:

There are many reasons why an .exe built for one platform cannot load or run on a different platform.

- Sam Varshavchik put it well:

> It's for the same reason a radiator for your Toyota won't fit into a
> Dodge

- More to the point, an ["executable image"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) is much more than just "the machine code".
- An .exe is an example of "executable images".  They come in many different formats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Executable_file_formats.  Most of these formats are platform-specific.
- Any image must be [loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)) by the operating system in order to become a running [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).  This, too, is platform-specific.
- The running process will need resources like file I/O , memory and shared libraries, which are also platform-specific.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubts. So the compiler is different for different os right ? But finally they are in machine code, then why they cannot run in any platform ?

Comment: @ManjunathBhat `So the compiler is different for different os right ?` Partially, yes. `But finally they are in machine code, then why they cannot run in any platform ?` Because the system API and ABI are different.

Comment: @Manjunath Bhat: an "executable image" is much more than just "the machine code".  There are many reasons why an .exe built for one platform cannot load or run on a different platform.  See my updates above for a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you compiled the code using `g++` on Linux, you should be able to run it on Linux but it won't work on Windows because the binary executable is compiled for Linux.

On Windows, `.exe` is the extension of the executable file but the binary code must be compiled for Windows so that it can run. On Linux, you can use any extension, `.mp4` or anything and it will still run when typing `./program.mp4` in terminal.

Comment: But finally they are in machine code, then why they cannot run in any platform ?

Comment: It's for the same reason a radiator for your Toyota won't fit into a Dodge.

Comment: About executing on different OS, Linux uses ELF format and Windows uses PE format. What you compiled was an ELF binary file so it won't run on Windows. OSes also have different kernel APIs so Linux executable won't run on Windows.